# InetAddress can't resolve some domains, throws java.net.UnknownHostException, but domains actually work in the browser

Tags: java, inetaddress

InetAddress fails to resolve the following domains:

```
kymcolux.com
shencan.net
zoocore.com
```

Tested on my home computer and a VPS with:

```
InetAddress addr1 = InetAddress.getByName("kymcolux.com");
```

https://httpstatus.io/ also can't fetch the URLs.

InetAddress throws:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: zoocore.com: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1055)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Strangely they work in my browser.

**UPDATE**
Tried different DNS servers (Google & OpenDNS). Still the same result.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your Browser auto adds `www` or `http`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if it works when you append **www** to the urls as shown below:

```
InetAddress addr1 = InetAddress.getByName("www.kymcolux.com");
```

Comment: omfg... I don't want to live on this planet anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The following sites are not even reachable from my browser without adding the www. initially. You might be able to open them in your browser if you previously visited these sites.

Note the following output:

```
java.net.InetAddress.getByName("google.com");//google.com/216.58.208.238            
java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");//www.google.com/216.58.210.196
```